# Reorder the rows of matrices following the elements of a column vector

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix

I have a vector `A` in MATLAB of dimension `(M*N)x2` reporting in the first column the integers from `1` to `M` in ascending order each one repeated `N` times, and in the second columns some random numbers.

E.g., if `M=4` and `N=3`,

```
A=[1 0.1;
   1 0.2;
   1 0.3;
   2 0.4; 
   2 0.5;
   2 0.6;
   3 0.7;
   3 0.8;
   3 0.9;
   4 1.1;
   4 1.2;
   4 1.3];
```

Then I have a 3d matrix `C` of dimension `(M*N)x2xR`, where `C(:,:,h)` has `A(:,1)` as first column and some random numbers in the second column, for any `h=1,...,R`.

E.g., if `R=2`,

```
C(:,:,1)=[1 1.4;
          1 1.5;
          1 1.6;
          2 1.7; 
          2 1.8;
          2 1.9;
          3 2.1;
          3 2.2;
          3 2.3;
          4 2.4;
          4 2.5;
          4 2.6];

C(:,:,2)=[1 2.7;
          1 2.8;
          1 2.9;
          2 2.10; 
          2 2.11;
          2 2.12;
          3 2.13;
          3 2.14;
          3 2.15;
          4 2.16;
          4 2.17;
          4 2.18];
```

Then, I have a vector `B` of dimension `Mx1` reporting M numbers in `{1,...M}` **in a random order with possible repetitions**.

E.g.,

```
B=[3;4;2;2]
```

I want to reorder `A` and `C` following the order of the elements in `B`: more precisely, in the example above I want to list firstly all the rows of `A` starting with `3`, the all the rows of `A` starting with `4`, etc., and similarly with `C`.

```
A_reordered=[3 0.7;
             3 0.8;
             3 0.9;
             4 1.1;
             4 1.2;
             4 1.3
             2 0.4; 
             2 0.5;
             2 0.6;             
             2 0.4; 
             2 0.5;
             2 0.6]
C_reordered(:,:,1)=[3 2.1;
                    3 2.2;
                    3 2.3;
                    4 2.4;
                    4 2.5;
                    4 2.6;
                    2 1.7; 
                    2 1.8;
                    2 1.9;
                    2 1.7; 
                    2 1.8;
                    2 1.9];

C_reordered(:,:,2)=[3 2.13;
                    3 2.14;
                    3 2.15;
                    4 2.16;
                    4 2.17;
                    4 2.18;
                    2 2.10; 
                    2 2.11;
                    2 2.12;
                    2 2.10; 
                    2 2.11;
                    2 2.12];
```

What I am doing now is:

```
 A_reordered=zeros(N*M,2);
 C_reordered=zeros(N*M,2,R); 
 for m=1:M
     A_reordered((m-1)*N+1:m*N,:)=A(A(:,1)==B(m),:);
     for r=1:R
         C_reordered((m-1)*N+1:m*N,:,r)=C(C(:,1,r)==B(m),:,r); 
     end
 end
```

However this is slow for `M` and `R` large. How can I improve the speed of this operation?

**EDIT**
I thought about this

```
 idx=arrayfun(@(x)find(A(:,1)==x,1),B);
 idx_final=kron(idx, ones(N,1))+repmat((0:1:N-1)',M,1);
 A_reordered=A(idx_final,:);
 C_reordered=C(idx_final,:,:);
```

Do you have faster suggestions?

Comment: I just edited two of your questions; please read especially the following meta question: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) Just ask a question, like I did there, and don't simply ask for help.

Comment: How do you feel about reshaping your `A` and `C` matrices so that all rows in each 2-dimensional plane contain the same value for column 1? In other words, `A` would become a `3x2x4` matrix.

Comment: Would that be convenient even with `M,N,R` large?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use `find`. You can just calculate the required indices using `N` and `B`. And you can use [`bsxfun`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to make things fast.

```
idx = bsxfun(@plus, 1:N, N*(B-1)).';
```

Then do whatever you like, e.g.

```
A_reordered=A(idx(:),:);
C_reordered=C(idx(:),:,:);
```

Comment: Very neat . +

Comment: Thanks. This is, in fact, my first answer using bsxfun!

Comment: btw it is a better practice to use [transpose `.'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) instead of [complex conjugate transpose `'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) when you are meant to take transpose even when dealing with real numbers. And starting from R2016b, you can use implicit expansion. `idx = ((1:N) + N*(B-1)).';`